# How to assert and test a ReactJS / Fluxible Component's state?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, fluxible

My app is a Fluxible / React application.

I have the following spec that attempts to test a LoginForm. Embedded components have been stubbed using rewire. I referenced http://fluxible.io/api/components.html#testing.

The first spec it("renders") passes. However, when I try to do more tests as shown in the commented code, the test fails.

I am unable to assert on LoginForm's state or trigger simulated events using TestUtils on the component. Are there any ways to do that?

```
import React from 'react/addons';;
import { createMockComponentContext } from 'fluxible/utils';
import createStore from 'fluxible/addons/createStore';

var rewire = require("rewire");
var rewireModule = require("../../helpers/rewire-module");

// stub inner components with LoginForm
// `rewire` instead of `require`
var LoginForm = rewire("../../../src/components/auth/login-form");

// Replace the required module with a stub component.
rewireModule(LoginForm, {
  FormattedMessage: React.createClass({
    render: function() { return <div />; }
  }),
  NavLink: React.createClass({
    render: function() { return <div />; }
  })
});

describe('LoginForm', function() {
  var context;
  var TestUtils;
  var provideContext;
  var connectToStores;
  var MockIntlStore;
  var MockAuthStore;
  var noop = function(){};
  var component;

  beforeEach(function(){

    MockIntlStore = createStore({
      storeName: 'IntlStore',
      getMessage: noop,
      getState: function(){
        return {}
      }
    });

    MockAuthStore = createStore({
      storeName: 'AuthStore'
    });

    context = createMockComponentContext({
      stores: [MockIntlStore, MockAuthStore]
    });

    // React must be required after window is set
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils
    provideContext = require('fluxible/addons/provideContext');
    connectToStores = require('fluxible/addons/connectToStores');

    // Wrap with context provider and store connector
    LoginForm = provideContext(connectToStores(LoginForm, [MockIntlStore, MockAuthStore], function (stores) {
      return {
      };
    }));

    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <LoginForm context={context} />
    );

  });

  it("renders", function() {


    var foundComponent = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(
      component, 'login-form');

    expect(foundComponent).toBeDefined();
  });

  // TODO fluxible wraps components so we cant reach the inner component to assert on state and trigger event handlers

  // it("should have an initial state", function() {

  //   let initialState = {
  //     username: '',
  //     pass: ''
  //   }

  //   expect(component.state).toEqual(initialState);
  // });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `provideContext` and `connectToStores`, your component is wrapped. You have done it right to find the component using `TestUtils. findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass`, Simply use the foundComponent for test, that is what is being tested. i.e.

```
...
var foundComponent = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(
  component, 'login-form');
expect(foundComponent.state).toEqual(initialState);
...
```

Comment: Although I really think this is the right answer, I have had no luck getting this to work :( As in, my state is just null

Comment: My object: `... state: null__proto__: ReactClass.createClass.Constructor`

Comment: Could you please post your code ? Did you render your component before testing the states ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a solution:

```
    var tbg = React.createElement(x, { di: serviceLocator });
    var renderer = React.addons.TestUtils.createRenderer();
    var rtbg = renderer.render(tbg);
```

Then your method is here:

```
    renderer._instance._instance.myMethod
```

Where myMethod is a function member of component `x`